# Is there a way use a different command besides echo (do rm file) inside a conditional in unix

Tags: bash, if-statement, unix

okay, I am reading the filenames from filelist.txt; for each line in filelist.txt I want to run a command `lar -c`.

To test my code I only want to run on the first line.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

fileList=/path/to/fileList.txt
count=1
if [[ $count == 1]]; then
  #getting the first line of the txt file
  line=$(sed "${count}q;d" $fileList)
  #execute my command
  do lar -c $line
fi;
count=`expr $count +1`
```

but when i try to execute my .sh file i get the following error

```
./ReadFilesFirstBatch.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

I apologize I'm very new to bash coding but I want to figure this out!

Comment: `do` is a keyword reserved by bash, which is used by while, for loops in their syntax not sure why you are using `do lar -c $line`, you need not to mention do here.

Comment: See `help if` for the construct if an `if-statement`

Comment: I see! thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a `while read loop`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fileList=/path/to/fileList.txt

while read -ra line; do
  echo lar -c "${line[@]}"
done < "$fileList"
```

- The -a option is needed when using read so you build an array each line, other wise you will need `eval` which you should not be using (at least for now)
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.
- See  [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- Try also [shellckheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) if you want to validate your script.

Answer (score 0):

Was is the `do` supposed to do anyway? Simply write

```
lar -c "$line"
```

without the `do`. Don't forget the quotes, just for the case `line` contains a space.

BTW, the last line can be written simpler as

```
((count++))
```